# Is there a way to sense if there is a # besides the .html link? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, file, hyperlink

I have a simple HTML file, it just displays this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Hello</p>
   </body>
   <script>
    //Nothing yet
   </script>
</html>
```

Usually when you go to an HTML file locally, its something like file:///C:/Users/Onedrive/ect/file.html.You can add #'s next to the "link" and nothing will happen. Is there a way to tell if there is a # next to the link with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean if the link has an '#' sign at the end you can use:

```js
window.location.toString().endsWith('#');
```